# How to remove only one max (min) from a list using Java 8 stream API in O(N) time and O(C) space complexity

Tags: java, java-8, max, java-stream

Here is a code for removing only one of the max values (in this case the first one, but this is irrelevant) from the list. It is `O(n)` in time and `O(n)` in space (beyond the input).

```
public List<Integer> removeOneOfTheMax(List<Integer> nums) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxIndex = -1;
    Iterator<Integer> it = nums.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
        Integer temp = it.next();
        if (max < temp) {
            maxIndex = i;
            max = temp;
        }

    }
    nums.remove(maxIndex);
    return nums;
}
```

**1.** What would be the equivalent of the method using the Java 8 stream API? I would like to preserve the time and space complexity, so no sorting is allowed.

**2.** Actually, if you pass a `LinkedList` into the above code the space complexity would be `O(C)` (again, beyond the input), but as far as I understand the `.stream()` creates an additional data structure so a stream API equivalent must be at least `O(N)` in space. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you think that this is “`O(n)` in space”? Since the already existing `List` does not count, there is no memory requirement that scales with the list size. This is `O(1)` in space, regardless of whether you use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. That would be different when using `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but it wouldn’t be the algorithm’s responsibility.

Comment: Eliminating an element from ArrayList in the worst case involves creating a new array and recopying all elements to it. This does not happen in case of LinkedList.

Comment: `ArrayList.remove(int)` [never does that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#491). Maybe you are confusing it with `add`. However, even if it was that expensive, it was not a property of your algorithm.

Comment: You are indeed right, but in this case I have another question. Does a once huge ArrayList keep storing (after a lot of `.remove(int index)` calls) a huge array of nulls forever?

Comment: Indeed. Unless you call `trimToSize()`, it will never shrink its array. Though, there is no explicit specification regarding this behavior. All the spec says, is, that the capacity will grow as necessary (non-linearly, to guaranty a “constant amortized time cost”).

Comment: @GA1 Holger's last point is true not only for ArrayList, for almost all other types like these. HashMap internal array will not shrink either on removal of elements.

Comment: @Holger your comments here have answered more questions that the OP had, then the actual answer I posted. Would you please add those as an answer that I will be more then happy to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream solution *could* look like this:

```
int maxIndex = IntStream.range(1, nums.size()).reduce(0, (i, j) -> {
    int left = nums.get(i);
    int right = nums.get(j);
    return Integer.max(left, right) == left ? i : j;
});

nums.remove(maxIndex);
```

Underneath there is going to be a `Spliterator`.

The stream operation itself is not going to create additional data structures.

Comment: Usually, using existing methods is recommended, but here, it only makes the code more complicated. The entire lambda expression can be simplified to `(i, j) -> nums.get(i)>=nums.get(j)? i : j`.

Comment: This + the answer is what I was looking for