# Understanding ArrayBuffer in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to undersatend how removing elements from `ArrayBuffer` works. Here is it:

```
  override def remove(n: Int, count: Int) {
    if (count < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("removing negative number of elements: " + count.toString)
    else if (count == 0) return  // Did nothing
    if (n < 0 || n > size0 - count) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("at " + n.toString + " deleting " + count.toString)
    copy(n + count, n, size0 - (n + count))
    reduceToSize(size0 - count)
  }
```

The thing is copy is implemented as follows:

```
protected def copy(m: Int, n: Int, len: Int) {
  scala.compat.Platform.arraycopy(array, m, array, n, len)
}
```

It means it just copies the content of the new array to the same array ***without resizing it***. In contrast, `ArrayList` in `JDK` resizes array as long as we delete elements from it.

Where is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduceToSize` method reduce the size of array I think.

```
  def reduceToSize(sz: Int) {
    require(sz <= size0)
    while (size0 > sz) {
      size0 -= 1
      array(size0) = null
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not quite clear. Is it exactly the same if we set null as recreating array with a new size?

Comment: @St.Antario Recreating array is much more expensive, so just set the element to null and make GC can do its work is more appropriate. We don't really care about the real size of the inner array, but the value of private field `size0`.

Answer (score 1):

For the **Java** `ArrayList` it also not **shrink** the **data array**, just set the `null` for the **removed** **elements** for **GC** them. **Scala** `ArrayBuffer` has done nearly same thing with `ArrayList`

```
public E remove(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData(index);

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                         numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Comment: So it means we actually have an array of the same size, but with the elements set to null, right?

Comment: Yes, maybe this post is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933700/why-java-arraylists-do-not-shrink-automatically